# Google Provisioning API: read-only access without admin account. Possible?

Tags: provisioning, google-data-api

For my project I need to have read-only access for my GApps-for-Domain domain-specific data. E.g. retrieve all users, their details, domain groups etc. Seems, that is not possible without providing domain administrator's login and password.

As I understand it means I must have admin account credentials listed somewhere in my code. This is not secure, especially in case there are several committers on the project, and I do not want to share this sensitive information with them.

Is is possible to have read-only account providing, say, only simple non-admin account credentials of domain user?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have a read-only account with ClientLogin but you may want to use OAuth for authentication and avoid passing your credentials.